# Ansible "missing become password" on one machine but not another

Tags: linux, ansible, sudo

The situation is this: From Machine A on target Machine B, I run the below shell code and it completes SUCCESSfully. From Machine A on target machine C, I run the below shell code and it gives me "become password missing". I can log into both machine A and B with the credentials without being prompted for a sudo password or anything.

I go into Ansible.cfg and uncomment ask_sudo_pass and that causes the code to prompt me with a sudo password request. However, I want to automate this for dozens of machines, I can't enter a sudo password for every one every time I use this. I'm currently in the process of setting up SSH keys for these machines, but there's been delays there so I need a way to automate this in the short term. Any suggestions please?

These are the shell commands I'm using:

`export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False
sshpass -p ${SSH_PASSWORD} ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yml -u ${SSH_USERNAME} --extra-vars="ssh_user=${SSH_USERNAME}"`

Answer (score 0):

I usually remove the password of the user on the target with

```
passwd --delete username
```

and I rely on my id_rsa only to connect, of course my "username" on the target is part of the wheel group.

You can also try to edit the sudoers file and add something like this

```
your_username  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Hope this helps,